# DNS changing .bat script works on Win7 but not on Win10

Tags: windows, batch-file

So, this is the code:

```
:: Set primary and alternate DNS for IPv4 on Windows Server 2000/2003/2008 & 
:: Windows XP/Vista/7
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

netsh interface ipv4 set dns "Local Area Connection" static 8.8.8.8
netsh interface ipv4 add dns "Local Area Connection" 8.8.4.4 index=2

:EOF
```

It works fine when I run it on Windows 7 (my desktop) but it doesn't work on Windows 10 (my laptop). Any idea why?

Comment: Saying it doesn't work does not help anyone debug your program.  Run each of those `NETSH` commands at a command prompt and update your question with any error messages you are getting.

Comment: Are you sure that the `Windows 10` notebook is using, or has, a wired connection with the name `Local Area Connection`?

Comment: @Squashman, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Sorry, but I failed to state that I have no knowledge of programming. This code was found on the web and I was following a YouTube tutorial.

Comment: @Compo, speaking of that, my desktop has a wired connection whereas my laptop is always connected wirelessly.

Comment: @Jay then you probably shouldn't be screwing around with any of these settings with batch file. Why don't you change it through the Windows GUI. This website was created so programmers could help other programmers with their code. We are not here to teach you how to program or how to use your computer.